# Como obter o valor de algum ítem do select ao clicar sobre ele

Tags: javascript, html, html5, select, option

No fonte apresentado abaixo, a lógica tem falha ao capturar o clique sobre o elemento do `select` retornando apenas o primeiro `option`, e pelo que parece é um problema de índice - `selectedIndex`.

**Observe**:

```js
        function selecionar(link) {

                <!-- aqui chamamos as duas divs no nosso html: descricao -->

                var element1 = document.getElementById("poster");
                var element2 = document.getElementById("titulo");

                    <!-- ISSO DEVERIA FUNCIONAR CONFORME PRETENDIA - jogar o conteúdo do texto dentro do controle da condição para ser comparado sem repetição. Infelizmente ainda há problema -->
                    
    var el = document.getElementById("lista")
        var opt = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;

                <!-- A rotina abaixo, faz o trabalho de capturar só a string após a última barra invertida "/" -->

                var urlcomp = link;
                var tamurl = urlcomp.length;
                for (var i = tamurl; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (urlcomp.substring(i, i - 1) == '/') {
                        var antes = i;
                        var depois = urlcomp.substring(antes, tamurl);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                <!-- Daqui em diante, o controle de fluxo 'if' nos dirá o qual informação deve ser apresentada através do que o usuário escolheu -->

                if (depois == opt) {
                        element1.innerHTML = "<img src='https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.jpg' width='126' height='90'>";
                        element2.innerHTML = "<p>big buck bunny</p>";
                    } else if (depois == opt) {
                        element1.innerHTML = "<img src='https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.jpg' width='126' height='90'>";
                        element2.innerHTML = "<p>madagascar 2</p>";
                    } else if (depois == opt) {
                        element1.innerHTML = "<img src='https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.jpg' width='126' height='90'>";
                        element2.innerHTML = "<p>procurando dory</p>";
                    } else if (depois == opt) {
                        element1.innerHTML = "<img src='https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/meu_malvado_favorito_2.jpg' width='126' height='90'>";
                        element2.innerHTML = "<p>meu malvado favorito 2</p>";
                        }
                    }
```

```css
    select { color: red; }
```

```html
<select id="lista" onchange="selecionar(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>

 <option value="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny">big_buck_bunny</option>

 <option value="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2">madagascar_2</option>

 <option value="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory">procurando_dory</option>

 <option value="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/meu_malvado_favorito_2">meu_malvado_favorito_2</option>

</select>
<br><br>
    <p id="poster"></p>
    <p id="titulo"></p>
```

Vejo que **falta alguma coisa à mais** para instruir o código.

> **ACHO QUE** - Percorrer os ítens e apontar na variável `opt` o qual foi selecionado no `option`.

Porque quero fazer uso de variável que é bem mais prático e elegante. Tipo assim:

```
            var el = document.getElementById("lista")
            var opt = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;

                if (depois == opt) {
                        ...
                    } else if (depois == opt) {
                        ...
                    } else if (depois == opt) {
                        ...
                    } else if (depois == opt) {
                        ...
                        }
                    }
```

E evitar de preencher manulamente:

```
                if (depois == 'big_buck_bunny') {
                        ...
                    } else if (depois == 'madagascar_2') {
                        ...
                    } else if (depois == 'procurando_dory') {
                        ...
                    } else if (depois == 'meu_malvado_favorito_2') {
                        ...
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: não seria mais simples passar só o elemento: `onchange(selecionar(this))` e na *function* selecionar pegar o value: `var valor=link.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de repetir código, sugiro colocar como `value` nas options o nome do poster e como texto o título do filme, armazenando numa variável a URL da pasta das imagens, já que todas são iguais. Imagine ter que fazer um `if` para cada item!

Então, o código ficaria assim (veja comentários no código):

```js
function selecionar(i) {

   // pego a option selecionada
   var opt = document.querySelectorAll("#lista option")[i];

   // pego o valor da option
   var valor = opt.value;
   
   // pego o texto da option
   var titulo = opt.textContent;

   // guardo a URL numa variável, já que são todas iguais
   var local = "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/";

   <!-- aqui chamamos as duas divs no nosso html: descricao -->

   var element1 = document.getElementById("poster");
   var element2 = document.getElementById("titulo");

   <!-- A rotina abaixo, captura só a string após a última barra invertida "/" -->

   element1.innerHTML = "<img src='"+local+valor+".jpg' width='126' height='90'>";
   element2.innerHTML = "<p>"+titulo+"</p>";
}
```

```html
<select id="lista" onchange="selecionar(this.selectedIndex)">
   <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="big_buck_bunny">big buck bunny</option>
   <option value="madagascar_2">madagascar 2</option>
   <option value="procurando_dory">procurando dory</option>
   <option value="meu_malvado_favorito_2">meu malvado favorito 2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<p id="poster"></p>
<p id="titulo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta obter o atributo `value`:

```js
document.getElementById('lst').addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log('valor selecionado: ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="lst">
  <option value="http://www.meusite.com.br" selected="selected">item1</option>
  <option value="https://wwww.seusite.net">item2</option>
  <option value="ftp://www.seuendereco.com">item3</option>
</select>
```